# "ReferenceError: message is not defined" when trying to create a Discord.js bot

Tags: discord.js

Just a heads up, I'm not good with code and I'm new to the coding scene. I'm trying to create a Discord bot for our server.

Right now the command is ping and I'm having some issues.

```
    client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'o!ping') {
    ping = msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp
    msg.reply("Pong!\n\n The latency is" + ping + "ms.");
  }
});
```

The error occurs at the "ping = msg.." line here's the error:

```
ReferenceError: message is not defined
at Client.<anonymous> (D:\Bot\bot.js:55:35)
at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (D:\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (D:\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (D:\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (D:\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
```

Line 55 is "ping = msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp". Please help!

Comment: Well you pass the message object as `msg`, and then try to reference it as `message`, which doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

You passed `msg` in the callback function, so replace `message` with `msg`.

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'o!ping') {
    ping = msg.createdTimestamp - msg.createdTimestamp
    msg.reply("Pong!\n\n The latency is" + ping + "ms.");
  }
});
```